# Using sort() function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I use the `sort()` function of jQuery on a click event to organize it by date the  `<div>`s, the sorting works only the first time. Then the `<div>`s arrange themselves in random order in the next click. Could someone help me in this problem?

```
function orderDate(tipo){
    var nposX = 0;
    var nposY = 0;

    if(tipo == 'acrescente'){
        $("#ordeData").attr({'onclick' : 'orderDate("decrescente");'});
    }else if(tipo == 'decrescente'){
        $("#ordeData").attr({'onclick' : 'orderDate("acrescente");'});
    }


    function lxp(a, b){
        alert($(a).html());
        var adate = new Date($(a).attr("data-date"));
        var bdate = new Date($(b).attr("data-date"));
        if(tipo == 'acrescente'){
            return adate > bdate ? -1 : 1;
        }else if(tipo == 'decrescente'){
            return adate < bdate ? -1 : 1;
        }
    }

    $("#blocoSite li").sort(lxp).each(function(i, el){

        $("#blocoSite li").each(function(is, els){
            nposX = $(els).offset().left;
            nposY = $(els).offset().top;

            if(i == is){
                return false;
            }
        });

        $(this).animate({
            left: nposX,
            top :  nposY
        }, 800);
    });
}
```

Comment: Rather than that `if/else` where you assign click events using `attr` you should do: `$("#ordeData").click(function(){ orderDate(tipo); });`

Comment: Can you set up some sample markup and scripts on http://www.jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @Paulpro: No, you'd need to use [`.one("click", …)`](http://api.jquery.com/one/). Otherwise you would pile up the listeners, and end in an ugly mess of interfering up-down sorts.

Comment: @DouglasSilva: You know that `.sort()` only reorders your current collection, but not the nodes in the DOM?

Comment: @Bergi: Then he orders once?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3T5kN/  Looks like the sorting itself works.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan: Yes it works! however when I click one more time, the intention was that he would be in descending order ...

Comment: ... Did you click the button twice on that JS Fiddle?  It works up AND down.

Comment: here is not working click to go back to declining